# is there any way?MySQL delete all of the new content created within a specific time (in all tables)

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I've a MySQL database compromised by site breaching,
this violation is recent and I would like to recover this DB deleting all new data inserted in the last 6 month.

I've search through mysqldump options and by the MySQL "WHERE" function but whit no luck.

Is there any way?

Thanks

Comment: There aren't any timestamps on the data inserted to the database, much easier to restore from backup which I assume you don't have.

Comment: I succeeded in the management of the problem and I was given a single DB. Thanks anyway.